# C# ASP.NET Buscar elementos de una lista de objetos por cada uno de sus campos

Tags: c#, asp.net

En C# tengo una lista de objetos "Papel" guardado en ViewState en el cual abastezco un panel de GridView, pero el problema es que la lista es muy grande y tengo hacer un textbox junto con un botón de búsqueda para filtrearlo, intente con este código para buscar pero el resultado me da entender que solo arroja los resultados mientras exista en los 2 campos (tengo mas campos por filtrar), y yo necesito que si alguno o muchos campo(s) contiene busX aparezca en la nueva lista una vez.

```
string busX = txtBusquedaPapeles.Text.Trim();
List<Papel> Papeles = (List<Papel>)ViewState["Papeles"];
List<Papel> BusPapeles = new List<Papel>();
BusPapeles =  Papeles.FindAll(x => x.StrDescripcion.Contains(busX)).FindAll(x => x.StrMedida.Contains(busX));

dgvPapeles.DataSource = BusPapeles;//gridview
dgvPapeles.DataBind();
```

Comment: No necesitas poner el prefijo `Str` a las propiedades de la entidad Papel, esta de mas

Comment: No necesitas declarar la instancia usando `List<Papel> BusPapeles = new List<Papel>();` si despues vas asignar el resultado de una operacion, puedes usar directo `List<Papel> BusPapeles = Papeles.FindAll(...) ` en la misma linea declaras y asignas la variable

Answer (score 2):

Existen varias formas de lograr lo que planteas, pero en todas ellas vas a tener que aplicar `Reflection` para descubrir dinamicamente las propiedades y poder comprarlas a todas con el valor que definas

[Reflection to Filter List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569795/reflection-to-filter-listt)

Esta interesante esta extension

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> MatchWithAnyProperty<T, TK>(this IEnumerable<T> list, TK value)
    {
        var argType = typeof (TK);
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(argType));

      return  list.Where(item => properties.Any(prop =>
            {
                var propertyValue = prop.GetValue(item, null);
                if (value == null)
                    return propertyValue == null;
                return propertyValue.Equals(value);
            }));
    }
}
```

En tu caso la usarias

```
var BusPapeles  = Papeles.MatchWithAnyProperty(busX);
```

Si quieres usar el `Contains()` imagino debas dataptar la comparacion cambianso el `Equals()`, algo como ser

```
return propertyValue.ToString().Contains(value);
```

Comment: Si, de hecho...

Comment: ¿El enlace que pusiste de "Reflection to Filter List" puedo encontrar el problema de conversión del string?, es la primera vez que veo reflection.

Comment: no entendi cual problema de "problema de conversión del string" ?

Comment: Disculpa no me explique bien, que si con ese enlace puedo resolver el problema de adaptar el Contains en lugar de Equals

Comment: deberia poder, puse al final como cambiaria la linea del propertyValue cuando evalua esta contra el value que se quiere comparar